# My function with reference is not working

Tags: php

I have a string, I json_decode it with second arg true to get a assoc array.

I now need to go through each string in there and stripslashes in it.

So I wrote this function:

```
function stripslashes_in_json(&$phpJsonDecodedTrue) {
    if (is_array($phpJsonDecodedTrue)) {
        foreach ($phpJsonDecodedTrue as &$v) {
            if (is_string($v)) {
                $v = stripslashes($v);
            } else if (is_array($v)) {
                stripslashes_in_json($v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it's not having on an affect on the json_decoded assoc array I pass into here, does anyone know whats up?

Comment: Have you considered the much simpler `array_walk_recursive($phpJsonDecodedTrue, function($v) {$v = stripslashes($v);})`? This does all of the recursive iteration for you internally.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` apart, your code [works](https://3v4l.org/Fkodd) well to me.

Comment: Thanks all! I just learned of array_walk_recursive that is real cool! Ill try to avoid stripslashes, it seems json_decode is actually stripping the slashes is that true?

Comment: What you mean? Are you referring to some characters (", \, \n, etc.) escaped in json? That has nothing to do with `stripslashes`, just rules for building a JSON string correctly

Comment: some sample input and expected output would be helpful

Comment: Thanks yeah I its the rules for building json correctly. Because my string is `Hi my name is "Blah"`. So it sent to the server as `{"name":"Hi my name is \"Blah\"}` and those slashes are removed, is that expected?

Comment: Yes it is. Otherwise your json wont be parsed correctly